# JDBC driver class not loading for JAVA app when it connects to Postgres in Docker

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, centos

I have a docker container set up locally with CentOS and Boot2Docker.  The goal is to install a JAVA application that connects to Postgres.  Java JDK and JRE for 1.8 are installed.  Postgres is up and running.  I am able to connect to it with psql and do work.

The Java application was compiled as a jar file with Intellij.  Attached is the POM.xml file.  All is well in intellij.  However, when I try to run the app in docker from the command line with: java -jar APP_NAME.jar, I get the following error message:

"PostgreSQL 9.4.1212.jre7

Found in: jar:file:/demo_data/out/artifacts/demo_data_jar/demo_data.jar!/org/postgresql/Driver.class

The PgJDBC driver is not an executable Java program.

You must install it according to the JDBC driver installation instructions for your application / container / appserver, then use it by specifying a JDBC URL of the form 
    jdbc:postgresql://
or using an application specific method.

See the PgJDBC documentation: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html

This command has had no effect."

Here is the POM:
    
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.align</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo_data</name>
<description>Program to create demo data for align care.</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jar you created is using the `main` class from the PostgreSql jdbc driver (that serves only to warn people that try to run it like `java -jar postgresql_jdbc.jar`, that it does not make sense).

So make sure while you create your jar, that you specify the right main class.

Comment: the main class was correctly referenced in the MANIFEST file as "Main Class: com.align.DemoDataApplication".  However, Intellij drops this file into a directory under src/java/META-INF/.  This does not work for Maven projects.  It needs to be under: src/resources/META-INF/.  Since the JRE could not find my main class, it did find the main class in the postgres driver and tried to run it instead.  I manually copied the MANIFEST to the resources folder, recompiled and it worked.  Thanks for your help.