# JDBC driver installation problem in Eclipse

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, jdbc

I have a problem with Eclipse/JDBC/PostgreSQL. I am learning Java and I cannot identify where does it come form. I have a first Java project named "DB1" in Eclipse which connects with a database (I worked with pgadmin4 for the database). Everything works fine with this one.
but when I create another project (to test it, I also copied my "DB1" in another java project that I renamed), I add the driver (I tried postgresql-42.2.20.jar and postgresql-42.2.18.jar), going to : build path -> libraries -> add external jar, then click on the file.

However, when I run my program (which works fine on another computer and also the "DB1" on my computer), I have a message saying:

```
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.20
Found in: jar:file:///C:/Users/Manu/Desktop/Eclipse%20Workspace/Pilotes/postgresql-42.2.20.jar!/org/postgresql/Driver.class

The PgJDBC driver is not an executable Java program.

You must install it according to the JDBC driver installation instructions for your application / container / appserver, then use it by specifying a JDBC URL of the form 
    jdbc:postgresql://
or using an application specific method.

See the PgJDBC documentation: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html

This command has had no effect.
```

Does anybody know what I can do? I tried several things (change version of driver, copy paste my old project with the jar included, create a new project from zero), but all the things I tried didn't work and as a beginner I don't really know where I have to look for a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC driver class not loading for JAVA app when it connects to Postgres in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839267/jdbc-driver-class-not-loading-for-java-app-when-it-connects-to-postgres-in-docke)

Comment: The error indicates that you are either trying to run the PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR as an application, or running a main-class in that driver, instead of your own application. If you created an executable JAR yourself, make sure that its manifest specifies your own main-class, not one from PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. if it can help somebody, I right-clicked on my main class and "run as"-> "java application" instead of the run button (similar to "play button"), and it works.